# Excel writing from listview is very slow

Tags: c#, excel

I'm exporting a listview that has six columns and about 50 items in it. When trying to export it to an Excel file it takes about 2 to 3 minutes. Code:

```
        linkLabel2.Text = "Please Wait...";
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range cells = wb.Worksheets[1].cells;
        cells.NumberFormat = "@";
        int i = 1;
        int i2 = 2;

        int x = 1;
        int x2 = 1;
        foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns)
        {
            ws.Cells[x2, x] = ch.Text;
            x++;
        }
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        {
            i = 1;
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                cells[i2, i] = lvs.Text;
                ws.Columns.AutoFit();
                if (lvs.Text.Contains(">"))
                {
                    cells[i2, i].Font.Color = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                }
                if (lvs.ForeColor == Color.Firebrick)
                {
                    cells[i2, i].Font.Color = Color.Firebrick;
                }
                else if (lvs.ForeColor == Color.Olive)
                {
                    cells[i2, i].Font.Color = Color.Olive;
                }
                else if (lvs.ForeColor == Color.LimeGreen)
                {
                    cells[i2, i].Font.Color = Color.LimeGreen;
                }
                else if (lvs.ForeColor == Color.Orange)
                {
                    cells[i2, i].Font.Color = Color.Orange;
                }


                i++;
            }
            i2++;
        }

        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        wb.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        wb.Close();
        linkLabel2.Text = "Export";

    }
```

Does anyone know how I can make this faster?

Comment: Just a quick observation, you can assign lvs.ForeColor to a variable in the nested foreach that way it's not always having to get the color on each if-then. That may shave off a few seconds. I would also use a switch statement rather than the else ifs.

Comment: I would move the `ws.Columns.AutoFit();` outside of the loop, but that certainly doesn't explain your performance problem.  I can't possibly imagine how 50 records with 6 columns would take more than a couple of seconds, even with the autofit happening each time.  I'd recommend putting in some diagnostics to see which lines of code are taking the longest amount of time.  Jonathan's suggestion might help a little, but for this volume of data we're talking nanoseconds, not minutes.

Comment: @Hambone You're definitely right, I use this to export thousands of rows of data and it only takes a minute, 2 at most.

Comment: Before the loop, put: app.ScreenUpdating=false; - then after the loop, put app.ScreenUpdating=true;